# Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Security OAUTH 2 SSO Failing with latest releases

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I am trying to upgrade a sample Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Security with OAuth from Spring Boot 1.4.1 + Brixton.RELEASE to Spring Boot 1.5.3+ Dalston.RELEASE. However, it has been a long hard try without any success.

It seems for some reason the resource server security filter chain is not getting fired. As a result the call to "/me" or "/user" is being handled by default security filter chain. I am thinking if this is a problem with order. But tried to explicitly set the order of the security filter chains as follows

- Auth Server 6
- Web Default 5
- Resource server 3 (hard coded ??)

Since the default filter chain is handling the request, it is always going to the login page, which generates HTML and the SSO client (server side thymeleaf web UI) fails.

The source code is below

**Authorization server**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyAuthServerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyAuthServerApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Then the authorization server configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(6)
public class AuthorizationServerConfigurer extends A 
uthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws 
Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("myauthserver")
            .secret("verysecretpassword")
            .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token")
            .scopes("myscope")
            .autoApprove(true);
}
}
```

Then the resource server class

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfigurer extends 
ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/user")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
}
}
```

The web MVC configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
 public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("login").setViewName("login");
 }
 }
```

The default spring security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(9)
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().csrf()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
{
    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
            .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
}
```

The resource controller

```
@RestController
public class ResourceController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/user" }, produces = "application/json")
public Map<String, Object> user(OAuth2Authentication user) {
    Map<String, Object> userDetails = new HashMap<>();
    userDetails.put("user", user.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal());
    userDetails.put("authorities",

AuthorityUtils.
 authorityListToSet(user.getUserAuthentication().getAuthorities()));
    return userDetails;
}
```

}

Finally the configuration - application.yml for the auth server

```
server:
  port: 9090
  contextPath: /auth

logging:
  level:
      org.springframework: INFO
      org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

The login.html Thymeleaf template is not shown here.

**OAUTH 2 SSO Client Web App**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyWebsiteApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyWebsiteApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

The web security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()   // Allow navigating to index 
 page,
            .anyRequest().authenticated();  // but secure all the other URLs
}
}
```

The web controller

@Controller
public class MyWebsiteController {

```
/**
 * Default index page to verify that our application works.
 */
@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String helloWorld() {
    return "Hello world!";
}

/**
 * Return a ModelAndView which will cause the 
'src/main/resources/templates/time.html' template to be rendered,
 * with the current time.
 */
@RequestMapping("/time")
public ModelAndView time() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("time");
    mav.addObject("currentTime", getCurrentTime());
    return mav;
}

private String getCurrentTime() {
    return LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);
}
}
```

The application configuration - application.yml for the client web app

```
server:
  port: 8080
  contextPath: /

security:
  oauth2:
  client:
    accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9090/auth/oauth/token
    userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9090/auth/oauth/authorize
    clientId: myauthserver
    clientSecret: verysecretpassword
  resource:
    userInfoUri: http://localhost:9090/auth/user
```

The Thymeleaf template for the time.html page is not shown here.

There must be some subtle little configuration thats wrong or some bug I do not know. Any help or ideas highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Guess was right the ordering of the security filter chain got was changed. Here is the link to the
[Spring 1.5.x release note](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes#oauth-2-resource-filter)

Modified code is here and will upload it to Github later. All changes on the auth server configuration.

The Spring security configuration - remove the @Order annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().csrf()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
{
    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
            .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
}
```

Then change the application.yml as follows

```
server:
  port: 9090
  contextPath: /auth

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: INFO
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG

security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
    filter-order : 3
```

That's it then the time is displayed on the client application /time url after authentication on the auth server.

Comment: Hey! Did you have time to add the code to github? I would really like to study it. Because I seem to have the same problem.